# how to copy all data of a docker context to another context?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-desktop

i recently install docker desktop on my Linux machine and it create a new docker context named desktop-linux. i have a default context and a desktop-linux context that old images and containers only show when when i use default context. in docker desktop when i create new container or pull an image they belong to desktop-linux context and docker desktop doesn't show old containers created in default context.

also docker ps show diffrenet result in each context.

how can i sync these two context?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using Docker Desktop on Linux?  It sounds like you're running two copies of Docker, one in the native Linux environment and one via the Desktop tool, and I might shut down one or the other.